# Sharepoint REST API columns(fields) and content types modification

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, content-type, column, sharepoint-fields

Does SharePoint REST API have some sort of modification time, flag, change token or ID for columns or content types modification?

For example, for a list item i can get last modified time from "Modified" field or version number from "OData__UIVersionString" and compare it to previous one and understand that item was changed:

```
{
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 20,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
        "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
        "ID": 20,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x01005C0A1C2A27BF5F4CB5D1ECC66DDD8E18003631706D98D7DF4187CD974B7D99C4C5",
        "Title": "newfiletest",
        "Modified": "2022-03-15T13:36:40Z",
        "Created": "2022-03-15T13:36:38Z",
        "AuthorId": 1073741822,
        "EditorId": 1073741822,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "3.0",
        "Attachments": true,
        "GUID": "63a511da-4a77-4367-ba91-e040d362014d",
        "ComplianceAssetId": null,
        "Body": null
    }
```

Comment: I just checked using `/fields` endpoint & I don't see any related column which shows modifications to columns.